# Problems when trying to send data from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to send data from one worksheet to another worksheet in a inactive workbook. The code copying the data correctly and closes my workbooks as I want, but it does not paste the data. I'm going to send data each month, and I want the new data to add after the old.

Could anyone help me find the error?

```
Sub Send()


Workbooks.Open Filename:="FILENAME"

Workbooks("NAME").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Range("A3:D19").Copy


ActiveWorkbook.Close True

Workbooks("NAME").Activate



erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to activate workbooks or worksheets to copy/paste data. 
Actually, it is good practice not to do that, since it is time-consuming and the screen is flickering when macro jumps between worksheets.

Here is the code how it should be done (comments in the code). You just need to put the paths to your source and destination files.

```
Sub Send()
    'Prefixes means:
    '   wkb - workbook
    '   wks - worksheet
    '   rng - range
    Dim wkbSource As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wkbDestination As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wksSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wksDestination As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Excel.Range
    Dim rngDestination As Excel.Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sourceFilePath As String
    Dim destinationFilePath As String
    '----------------------------------------


    'Defining paths to files.
    sourceFilePath = "..."
    destinationFilePath = "..."

    'Set references to source workbook, worksheet, range.
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sourceFilePath)
    Set wksSource = wkbSource.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A3:D19")

    'Set references to destination workbook, worksheet, range.
    Set wkbDestination = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=destinationFilePath)
    Set wksDestination = wkbDestination.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With wksDestination
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set rngDestination = .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 4))
    End With


    Call rngSource.Copy(Destination:=rngDestination)


    'Close files and clear variables.
    Call wkbSource.Close(False)
    Call wkbDestination.Close(True)

End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm in the workbook that is the source of the data, do I still need to set all the reference for that one?

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice to declare references to it, and use references instead of relying on active book/sheet.

Comment: I does not work here. I have figured out how i copy it it, but there is a problem when trying to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
Sub Send()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Name.xlsx")
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A3:D19").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wb.Close
End Sub
```

Doing it this way the `wb` has to be open till the `copy paste` is done. If you want to close it before you have to save all the data in an `object`. Correct me if I am wrong though.